# How to save an xlsx with openpyxl and get right encoding? [trash characters]

Tags: python, excel, encoding, sqlalchemy, openpyxl

I getting results from MYSQL DB and saving the data to an XLSX using openpyxl library. After saving and opening the file, I all names with any special characters full of bad characters. I believe this is some encoding problem, but I just can not find a way to set the encoding when opening or saving a workbook.

I have already tried to use:

```
wb =Workbook(encoding='utf8')
```

But then I get an error about unexpected keyword argument and I have no idea what else I can try.

The part of the code that deals with writing query result data to excel is here:

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet(0)
ws.append(res.keys())
x = res.fetchall()
xlength = len(x)
ylength = len(x[0])
for i in range(xlength):
    for k in range(ylength):
        ws.cell(row=(i+2), column=(k+1)).value = x[i][k]    
wb.save('Documents/python pigu_lt/reports/cache/{}'.format(query_type) + ".xlsx")
```

My actual result is:

```
'Vaikams ir kÅ«dikiams'
```

And my expected result is:

```
'Vaikams ir kūdikiams'
```

Does anyone know how to get this right?

Answer (score 1):

This has little to do with openpyxl and everything to do with MySQL and how you connect to it. XLSX stores data in XML which is UTF8 by default, and so capable of representing all unicode characters. You should check the settings for the database and make sure that it is returning either unicode or utf8.

Comment: I'd agree. `Å«` is the iso-8859-1 decoding of the bytes 0xc5 0xab, which is how UTF-8 encodes `ū`. So the DB connection is probably set up as iso-8859-1 or somesuch (or worse the data was mangled before being stored in the DB). Also note that MySQL's "utf8" is not actually utf8 (it only handles the Basic Multilingual Pane, you want utf8mb4).

Comment: Yeah, some utf8 -> latin-1 nonsense is probably happening before the data reaches openpyxl. Presumably the driver is defaulting to Latin1. How often do we see this? Only today I got a generated PDF with the utf8 - latin1 mess in it.